# Create associated object?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to grasp how to work with associated objects.

I have two objects

UserAttributes

```
    var sequelize = require('../database.js').sequelize,
        Sequelize = require('../database.js').Sequelize,
        User = sequelize.models.user,
        UserAttribute = sequelize.define('userAttributes', {
            name:       Sequelize.STRING,
            value:      Sequelize.STRING,
        });

    UserAttribute.belongsTo(User);
    module.exports = UserAttribute;
```

User

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        createRider: function(params) {
            var values = [],
                userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes,
                user = User.build(),
                name = userAttributes.build({name: 'name', value: 'params.name'}),
                fbprofile = userAttributes.build({name: 'fbprofile', value: 'params.fbprofile'}),
                phone = userAttributes.build({name: 'phone', value: 'params.phone'});

            user.save().then((user) => {
                console.log(user);
                user.adduserAttributes([name, fbprofile, phone]);
            });


        }
    }
});
```

For some reason adduserAttributes does not work. This is all the docs I've found on this.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/2.0/api/associations/

Comment: which version you are using @Himmators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BelongsTo` is a 1:1 relationship. This mean you can associate only one row to other table row.

Since its singular realtion setter method name will be `setUserAttribute()`, ([More docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto))

If you want to link multiple rows to a single row in another table you should use [hasMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#1m)

Comment: I get the same error. Currently I'm only adding the relation on the userAttribute, should I add it to the User aswell? The user hasMany, but the userAttribute only has one.

Comment: Yes you have to create the reverse relation too. You can add belongsTo on one side and hasMany on other side.

Comment: Now it ouputs Executing (default): UPDATE `userAttributes` SET `userId`=2,`updatedAt`='2016-06-23 20:33:32.086 +00:00' WHERE `id` IN (NULL, NULL, NULL), nothing seems to be added to userAttributes-table.

Comment: You need to save the name, fbprofile and phone first :) They dont have any primary key assigned (because they are not inserted yet)

Comment: oh, okay, Do I have to nest all the saves, like this  user.save().then((user) => {name.save().then()...

Comment: You can use Promise.all to do it in one step. Main goal is to have them saved before assigning to other relation

Comment: Not sure I understand how, I created a new question, if you can show a quick example that would be very helpful for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008348/how-to-avoid-nesting-when-saving-associated-objects