# How to avoid nesting when saving associated objects?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building my first sequelize model, as you can see it results in a lot of nesting when creating the associated objects

```
var values = [],
    userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes,
    user = User.build(),
    name = userAttributes.build({name: 'name', value: 'params.name'}),
    fbprofile = userAttributes.build({name: 'fbprofile', value: 'params.fbprofile'}),
    phone = userAttributes.build({name: 'phone', value: 'params.phone'});

user.save().then((user) => {
    name.save().then((name) => {
        fbprofile.save().then((fbprofile) => {
            phone.save().then((phone) => {
                user.addUserAttributes([name, fbprofile, phone]);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize has a [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) promise instance. From that you can use the [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) method

```
var values = [],
    userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes,
    user = User.build();

user.save()
  .then((user) => 
    sequelize.Promise.all([
       userAttributes.create({name: 'name', value: 'params.name'}),
       userAttributes.create({name: 'fbprofile', value: 'params.fbprofile'}),
       userAttributes.build({name: 'phone', value: 'params.phone'})
    ])
    .then((recordsArray) => 
       user.addUserAttributes(recordsArray);
    )
 );
```

Comment: The attributes seem to be added to the database as expected, but if I do `user.getUserAttributes()`, the response is `{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}`